# Implementing MSE loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning and I want to implement an autoencoder. I'm using **keras** and **mse loss function**. But when I use MSE function that I implemented althogh the output of my function and keras.losses.mse are approximately the same but the result is significantly worse.

Duo to some needs in my project I wanted to modify MSE. But when implemented the quality of the results became much worse.

The input of the function is two 23*32*3 ndarrays.
And I had to do slicing because of the modifications I wanted to do.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras as k

def custom_loss(im1, im2):
    im11 = im1[:, :, 0]
    im12 = im1[:, :, 1]
    im13 = im1[:, :, 2]
    im21 = im2[:,:,0]
    im22 = im2[:,:,1]
    im23 = im2[:,:,2]
    diff1 = tf.square(im11 - im21)
    diff2 = tf.square(im12 - im22)
    diff3 = tf.square(im13 - im23)
    res = tf.divide((diff1 + diff2 + diff3), 3)
    return res
```

but when I test it the results are almost the same. But when I use it in model the results are much worse.

```py
a = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)
b = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3)
v1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (32, 32, 3), 'v1')
v2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (32, 32, 3), 'v2')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    me = sess.run(custom_loss(v1, v2), feed_dict={v1: a, v2: b})
    true = sess.run(k.losses.mse(v1, v2), feed_dict={v1: a, v2: b})

for i in range(32):
    for j in range(32):
        print(i, j, true[i][j], me[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing summing of the diffs.

try:

```
def custom_loss(im1, im2):
    im11 = im1[:, :, 0]
    im12 = im1[:, :, 1]
    im13 = im1[:, :, 2]
    im21 = im2[:,:,0]
    im22 = im2[:,:,1]
    im23 = im2[:,:,2]
    diff1 = (im11 - im21)**2
    diff2 = (im12 - im22)**2
    diff3 = (im13 - im23)**2
    res = tf.divide((diff1 + diff2 + diff3).sum(), 3)
    return res
```